# Can i make a duplicate class as i can with functions

Tags: swift, generics, duplicates, codable

So i have this code where i'm trying to make an task handler for requests. But in some cases the request doesn't get an model in response and therefor i don't want it to process any data. Hard to explain, but code shown below:

```
class UserTask<T: Codable>: ExecuteProtocol {

    let userType: UserRequests

    init(userType: UserRequests) {
        self.userType = userType
    }

    var request: URLRequest {
        return userType.build
    }

    public func run(completion: @escaping ((Response<T, NAError>) ->())) {
        executeRequest(request: request) { (response) in
            switch response {
            case .success(let data):
                completion(NADecoder<T>.decode(data: data).model)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

class UserTask: ExecuteProtocol {

    let userType: UserRequests

    init(userType: UserRequests) {
        self.userType = userType
    }

    var request: URLRequest {
        return userType.build
    }

    public func run(completion: @escaping ((Response<Any?, NAError>) ->())) {
        executeRequest(request: request) { (response) in
            switch response {
            case .success(let data):
                completion(.success(nil))
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This of course say `Invalid redeclaration of 'UserTask'` But can i do this in any smooth way? I have tried making the Codable optional and then unwrapping it. But as i want to keep the type of it in Decodable purpose it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand why are you unable to make `T` as optional. What's the issue with that?

Comment: `UserTask<T: Codable?>` Doesn't work as it doesn't conform to `Codable` and besides you can unwrap `types`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create multiple classes for same functionality. You simply need to make some changes to a single class to support both your use-cases.

Instead of adding *generic* `<T>` to the `class UserTask`, add it to method `run(completion:)`, i.e.

```
class UserTask: ExecuteProtocol {
    let userType: UserRequests

    init(userType: UserRequests) {
        self.userType = userType
    }

    var request: URLRequest {
        return userType.build
    }

    public func run<T: Codable>(type: T.Type, completion: @escaping ((Response<T?, NAError>) ->())) {
        //your code here...
    }
}
```

Call it like,

```
task.run(type: YourType.self) { (response) in
    //add your code here...
}
```

Comment: Looking into it, encountered some bugs, i get back to you

Comment: How do i call this function? Don't know why i'm having problems with that part

Comment: Tried multiple cases.. `task.run(completion: { (response: (User, NAError>)) in` is one
`let _: User = task.run(completion: response in {}...` is another `'()' is not convertible to 'User'` is a error

Comment: Still requires me to send an model. `task2.run(type: nil) { (response) in` gives: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` Sorry if i wasn't clear in the question

Comment: I had to add an additional function for the nil value case. But you help me enough. Thank you